# how do i set a mock db for testing in sinatra?

Tags: rspec, mocking, sinatra, rspec2, neo4j

I have a sinatra app that uses neo4j as a graph db.
the app accesses the db through neography as a REST client.

I want to mock this client for testing purposes, using rspec.
what's the best practice to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options here:

One: Follow this link: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/writing-an-api-wrapper-in-ruby-with-tdd/

It explains step by step how to do it using webmock and the vcr gem.  The idea is you run your tests against a live database the first time, vcr records them, and afterwards your tests will run off the recorded answers.

Two: You can run your tests against a fresh db in a CI virtual machine environment.
Take a look at the travis.yml file for Neography:

script: "bundle exec rake neo4j:install neo4j:start spec --trace"

and the results:
http://travis-ci.org/#!/maxdemarzi/neography

Three: You can run a test db on a different port number than your dev or prod db, point neography to that in your spec file and have at it.

It's a good question, so I'll do a post on it on my blog one of these days at http://maxdemarzi.com

Comment: thanks max! I was more interested in the way of mocking a low level object that resides in sinatra, regardless of its actual functionality.

Comment: I found my answer. I also opened an issue in neography; you may want to have a look. https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography/issues/39

Answer (score 3):

Found my answer:

sinatra app:

```
require 'sinatra'

module Backend
  class Neography
    # stuff
  end
end

helpers Backend

before do
    @neo = Backend::Neography.new
end

get '/:id' do
  "#{@neo.get_node(params[:id])}"
end
```

rspec:

```
describe 'The App' do
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    Sinatra::Application
  end

  def mock_neography
    @neo_mock = mock("Backend::Neography")
    @neo_mock.stub!("get_node") {"something else"}
    Backend::Neography.stub(:new).with(any_args()).and_return(@neo_mock)
  end

  it "gets a node" do
    mock_neography
    get '/5'
    last_response.should be_ok
  end
end
```